# Mongoose - Get replica set primary

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, replicaset

I am building a node server using `mongoose`.

I have a few `mongodb` instances running as a `replica set` and I am connected to that set using `mongoose`.

I would like to get the RS primary server in my node server. if I could run the mongo command `rs.isMaster` that would be helpful.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Why do you think you need to do this? As long as you are providing correct details in the connection string the driver figures out to connect to the primary for you. If you are messing around with read preferences, then you probably should not be. You "should" be using a default read preference which is coming from the primary unless you really understand what you are doing. So if you are asking to detect the master, then it does not seem like you really understand and you should therefore stick to the defaults.

Comment: Hi @NeilLunn, I am trying to do this for monitoring reasons. I know that if I supply the correct connection details `mongoose` and the `mongodb` driver will take care of finding the primary DB in the replica set, but I would like to report on it and on when it changes

Comment: @Algosub it's probably best to keep your monitoring separate from your node server: they do two different jobs, in quite different ways, and trying to mix the two will lead to unnecessary complications. Better to use a dedicated monitoring tool; many of these come preconfigured with a good set of principles and alerts for MongoDB setups; for example LogicMonitor: https://www.logicmonitor.com/support/monitoring/applications-databases/mongodb/ (other monitoring solutions are also available).

Comment: @VinceBowdren, as a general rule you are probably right. I still have a specific use case where it makes sense to us here. And in any case, I don't think the the driver (mongoose in this case) library should limit function calls that are allowed by Mongo, don't you?